# Remove zeros from the beginning of string VBA or Function

Tags: vba, function, excel

I have an issue about removing zeros from the beginning of  a string. 
I have used

```
=trim(left(substitute(A1,"0"," "),3))
```

in string = **`'0060'`** PPC mobile phone
I want to have result equals to **`60`**. But this function gives me 6.

Not all my records start with double zeros. There can be one, two or three zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a UDF (User Define Function)

```
Function Strip0(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String
    s = CStr(r.Value)
    If s <> "0" Then
        Do While Left$(s, 1) = "0"
            s = Mid$(s, 2)
        Loop
    End If
    Strip0 = s
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Longer code but runs quickly over a range of values (permanently changing them) rather than use UDFs on an ongoing basis.

Uses variant arrays and regexp for efficiency.

```
Sub KillLeadingZeroes()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim lngCalc As Long
    Dim objReg As Object
    Dim X()


    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select range for the replacement of leadoimg zeroes", "User select", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0

    'See Patrick Matthews excellent article on using Regular Expressions with VBA
    Set objReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objReg.Pattern = "^0+"
    objReg.Global = False

   'Speed up the code by turning off screenupdating and setting calculation to manual
   'Disable any code events that may occur when writing to cells
    With Application
        lngCalc = .Calculation
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Test each area in the user selected range

    'Non contiguous range areas are common when using SpecialCells to define specific cell types to work on
    For Each rngArea In rng1.Areas
        'The most common outcome is used for the True outcome to optimise code speed
        If rngArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
           'If there is more than once cell then set the variant array to the dimensions of the range area
           'Using Value2 provides a useful speed improvement over Value. On my testing it was 2% on blank cells, up to 10% on non-blanks
            X = rngArea.Value2
            For lngRow = 1 To rngArea.Rows.Count
                For lngCol = 1 To rngArea.Columns.Count
                    'replace the leading zeroes
                    X(lngRow, lngCol) = objReg.Replace(X(lngRow, lngCol), vbNullString)
                Next lngCol
            Next lngRow
            'Dump the updated array sans leading zeroes back over the initial range
            rngArea.Value2 = X
        Else
            'caters for a single cell range area. No variant array required
            rngArea.Value = objReg.Replace(rngArea.Value, vbNullString)
        End If
    Next rngArea

    'cleanup the Application settings
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lngCalc
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    Set objReg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work if a space always follows the first number:

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1, FIND(" ", A1)), "#")
```

In case the *space* condition is not guaranteed, a UDF would be needed.